# What is the difference between functions and closures?

Tags: swift

I have been reading the swift programming guide in iBooks. Could someone explain to me what is the difference between a function and a closure. Is it just that it has no name and can be used in expressions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Functions are, in fact, just named closures. The following are at least conceptually equivalent:

```
let foo = { println("hello") }

func foo()->(){ println("hello") }
```

This gets a little more complicated in the case of using `func` to declare methods, as there's some interesting bits of sugar added regarding the automatic insertion of public named parameters, etc. `func myMethod(foo:Int, bar:Int, baz:Int)` becomes `func myMethod(foo:Int, #bar:Int, #baz:Int)`, for example.

But it's still true that even methods are just a specific case of closures, and if it's true of closures, it's true of functions and methods as well.

Comment: Basically just like `function () {...}` in JS?

Comment: Almost. In javascript, closures are anonymous functions. In Swift, functions are named closures. But I'll freely admit that distinction is mostly semantic and not very important.

Comment: "In javascript, closures are anonymous functions. In Swift, functions are named closures." These two definitions are equivalent. It sounds like there is no difference, semantic or otherwise.

Answer (score 12):

First, let's start with [definition of Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), as found in Wikipedia:

> In programming languages, a closure (also lexical closure or function
>   closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a
>   referencing environment—a table storing a reference to each of the
>   non-local variables (also called free variables or upvalues) of that
>   function.

Closure is the term that is used to refer to a function along with the variables from its environment that it "closes".

The definition of Closure in Swift is inline with *lambdas* and *blocks* in other languages like C# and Ruby.

As for the difference from functions, from the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html):

> Global and nested functions, as introduced in Functions, are actually
>   special cases of closures

So all functions are essentially closures that store references to variables in their context.

`Closure expressions` are convenient way of writing closures, and provides more terse syntax.

Comment: @jemmons - I am still adding the answer.

Comment: @jemmons - true. I usually iterate over my answers, but clicked submit too quick in this case.

Comment: Functions are a special kind of closures. One difference is function always start with "func" keyword. There are three kinds of closures:

1) Global functions – They have a name and cannot capture any values
2) Nested functions – They have a name and can capture values from their enclosing functions
3) Closure expressions – They don’t have a name and can capture values from their context