# Are instance methods closures?

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures

In the book, "Swift Programming Language 3.0", it mentioned that types of closure include:

> Global functions are closures that have a name and do not capture
> any values
>
> Nested function are closures that have a name and can
> capture values from their enclosing function
>
> Closure expression are
> unnamed closure written in a lightweight syntax that can capture
> values from their surrounding context

I was just wondering does a function that exist in class scope count as a closure? One can certainly pass around such function as an argument to other function, but is it a closure?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36576717/1226963

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Absolutely! Here's an example that uses the [`lowercased()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641392-lowercased) method of `String`.

```
let aClosure: (String) -> () -> String = String.lowercased


let anUpperCasedString = "A B C"
print(anUpperCasedString)

let aLowerCaseString = aClosure(anUpperCasedString)()
print(aLowerCaseString)
```

You can see that the type of this closure is `(String) -> () -> String`. This is because `String.lowercased` is completely unapplied, it has no clue what instance it's operating on.

Calling `aClosure(anUpperCasedString)` will return a closure that's now `() -> String`. Baked into it is the instance it'll operate on. Only when you call this new closure with no params (`()`), will it actually execute the body of `lowercased()`, operating on the instance you gave it in the previous step, and return you the `String` result.

As a consequence, this is also valid:

```
let aLowerCaseString = String.lowercased("QWERTY")()
```

It just does all the steps above in one inlined step.

This technique is called function currying. [This post](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) talks more about this technique (called function currying) as it applies to instance methods in Swift.

Comment: wow, your answer is simply amazing! thanks for explain it in a clear and easy to understand manner! really appreicate your help!

Comment: @TonyStark No problem :)