# What does let someThing = {} mean?

Tags: swift, function, closures

I've seen this in the book I'm reading but I don't know what it means and what it does. Is it something like a function? I've tried looking at the Swift language book by Apple but could not find the answer.

Thanks

Comment: Swift var init with Closure ("closure" being a keyword to master if you want to use Swift).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is mostly used for declaring `closure` in Swift.

e.g.

```
let something = { print("something") }
something()//prints 'something"
```

Here we are declaring closure named `something` and then calling it later.
We can declare closures with parameters also as:

```
let something = { (str: String) in
    print("something param: \(str)")
}

something("ok")//prints "something param: ok"
```

We can even declare closures with return value as:

```
let something = { (str: String) -> Bool in
    print("something param: \(str)")
    return true
}

let success = something("ok")//prints "something param: ok" and return true
```

Comment: From your examples, what is the difference between a function and a closure?

Comment: In Swift there's no big difference in `closure` and `func`. Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108667/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-closures)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should do the swift basics first. If you want to learn more about closures you can have a look at the following side:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html