# Create Swift closure to create a UIView

Tags: swift, closures, dry

I would like to apply DRY to the lines I'm creating in swift. How can I refactor this code so a closure is called? It resides on a viewcontroller.

```
var topLineView: UIView = {
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}()

var bottomLineView: UIView = {
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}()

var centerLineView: UIView = {
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}()
```

I tried creating a variable but that caused an error:

```
let lineView = {
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}

var centerLineView = lineView()
```

error (Unable to infer closure type etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift isn't able to infer the return type of your closure, so you need to tell it ahead of time that you are returning a `UIView`. This compiles and runs fine.

```
let lineView = { () -> UIView in
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}
var myViewFromClosure = lineView()
var myViewFromClosure2 = lineView()
var myViewFromClosure3 = lineView()
```

I personally would opt for a `function` instead of a `closure` in this case, however. Like this:

```
func lineViewFunc() -> UIView {
    let lineView = UIView()
    lineView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    lineView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    return lineView
}

var myViewFromFunc = lineViewFunc()
var myViewFromFunc2 = lineViewFunc()
var myViewFromFunc3 = lineViewFunc()
```

Comment: Definitely agree about the function. It's worth remembering that a function can be locally nested inside another function, and that makes a nice way to extract locally repeated code without polluting the outer namespace.

Comment: I tried a function but the complier complains that self is not initialized

Comment: @Rik you can share your implementation if you’d like

Comment: I ended up creating a separate class because a function would not work but also repeating myself in a similar situation because my manager said to use a function also but then I would have to make it optional

Comment: I guess I could just create an empty and use a method to configure it in viewdidload...

Comment: @Rik I added a function example in my answer

Comment: Also, it ultimately really doesn't matter if you're using a `function` or a `closure`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108667/what-is-the-difference-between-functions-and-closures

Answer (score 0):

The issue with a function is I have to call it before super.init, but self does not exist yet.